# PHP loop trough folders and delete old files/empty folders

Tags: php, filesystems

I have file system shown in picture. My task is to loop from temp folder to last subdirectory and delete files that is older than 30 days and also after that delete empty folders.

[image]

I am using "League flysystem/filesystem"

Here is what I got now:

```
use common\components\helper\FileHelper;
use League\Flysystem\StorageAttributes;

class Tmp
{
    /**
     * @throws \League\Flysystem\FilesystemException
     */
    public static function delete($starting_directory, $time_difference): void
    {
        $filesystem = FileHelper::tempFs();
        $expire = strtotime($time_difference);
        $structure = $filesystem->listContents($starting_directory)
            ->toArray();

        foreach ($structure as $data) {
            if ($data->isDir()) {
                $directory_data = $filesystem->listContents($data['path'])
                    ->toArray();
                if (count($directory_data) === 0) {
                    $filesystem->deleteDirectory($data['path']);
                }
                foreach ($directory_data as $directory) {
                    $filesystem->deleteDirectory($directory['path']);
                    self::delete($directory['path'], $time_difference);
                }
            } else if ($data->isFile() && $data['lastModified'] < $expire) {
                $filesystem->delete($data['path']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File updated. Right now files are deleted after x time and all empty folders except 1st one. First folder after temp deletes after second method init. I guess I am missing a little.

- every directory have no limit for subdirectories.
- Code must accept large amount of files

Comment: `
You can loop through like this and  recursion
 function removeDirectory($path) {

 $files = glob($path . '/*');
 foreach ($files as $file) {
  is_dir($file) ? removeDirectory($file) : unlink($file);
 }
 rmdir($path);

 return;
}
`

Comment: @SanK there is need for looping recursively but using League filesystem.

Comment: Probably if the directory `$temp_dir` is empty, `count($structure) == 0`

Answer (score 0):

Well... After two long days of learning and looking how things going I finally made a progress. I made a script for deleting "X time" old files and also empty folders. But still not sure how this script will affect memory with large amount of data.

Here is solution:

```
use common\components\helper\FileHelper;

class Tmp
{
    /**
     * @throws \League\Flysystem\FilesystemException
     */
    public static function delete($starting_directory, $time_difference): void
    {
        $filesystem = FileHelper::tempFs();
        $expire = strtotime($time_difference);
        $structure = $filesystem->listContents($starting_directory)
            ->toArray();

        foreach ($structure as $data) {
            if ($data->isDir()) {
                self::delete($data['path'], $time_difference);
                $directory_data = $filesystem->listContents($data['path'])
                    ->toArray();
                if (count($directory_data) === 0) {
                    $filesystem->deleteDirectory($data['path']);
                }
            } else if ($data->isFile() && $data['lastModified'] < $expire) {
                $filesystem->delete($data['path']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe someone have opinion about possible memory usage running this script?